# how can i store a file GRIB2 in postgreSQL use raster2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i have a GRIB2 file , i want store it into postgresql by use raster2pgsql, when i used the following code:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -b 1 -C -M gfs.tmp.grb2 grib_raster_test_msl00 |  psql -U razaiOS -d template_postgis
```

then show me the error:

```
BEGIN
ERROR:  type "raster" does not exist
LINE 1: ...raster_test_msl00" ("rid" serial PRIMARY KEY,"rast" raster);
                                                           ^
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
VACUUM
```

i don't know how add the type "raster", can anyone help me about this problem. thanks very much.

Comment: Did you enable postgis extension?

Comment: yes, i set the postgis extension enabled.

Comment: @plaes , thank you very much , i forgot  set the new db's extension.